# jquery on hover change image won't work?

Tags: jquery, image, hover

I am trying to create a simple effect as an exercise basically I want the image to change when I hover over it and revert back when I mouse off

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
        <head>
            <title>Change pics on event</title>
            <meta charset = "utf-8">
            <script src = "jsf/jquery-1.8.js"></script>
            <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "talkpics.css">

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id = "pic">
                <img id = "sk" src = "tpi/skutch.jpg">
                <div id = "speech">
                   <img src = "tpi/speech5.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function (){
                        $("#sk").hover(function(){
                        $(this).attr("src","tpi/skutch2.jpg");
                            }, function(){
            $(this).attr("src", "tpi/skutch.jpg");          
                              }
                });
            });
            var sb = new Array();
                sb[0] = 'tpi/speech1.png';
                sb[1] = 'tpi/speech2.png';
                sb[2] = 'tpi/speech3.png';
                sb[3] = 'tpi/speech4.png';
                sb[4] = 'tpi/speech5.png';



            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

the array is part of something else I want to add later which is a random png speech bubble ..basically I want the image to change with a random speech bubble when you roll over it. but for now my issue is getting the skutch image to change. I have followed tutes on the net and have coded as examples have given but it won't work the image stays on skutch.jpg. I'm not sure why any help would be awesome.

```
*{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
border:none;
}

#pic{
height:500px;
width:500px;
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#sk{
position:relative;
}
#speech{
position:relative;
top:-450px;
left:-20px;
}
```

Comment: looks good to me.  fiddle it please.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this is the issue, but you have a extra bracket over here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sk").hover(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "tpi/skutch2.jpg");
    }, function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "tpi/skutch.jpg");
    //}  <== Not needed, comment it out...
    });
});
```

Comment: thanx ..removed bracket but it still doesn't work ...hmmm..also the code is neater on my Aptana doc but transferred here weirdly.

Comment: got it to work I had the wrong file extension for my second pic..duh..problem now is that my speech5.png isn't visible when I hover over so I get the new image but lose the png ..hmm..anyway I'm gonna fiddle with it some more..thanx for helping with my sloppy mistakes

Comment: Yeah, mistakes do happens, but we should quickly learn from them and neaver repeat them again :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you format your code with nicer indenting you'll see you have an extra `}` that shouldn't be there, which is a syntax error that stops it working:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#sk").hover(function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", "tpi/skutch2.jpg");
                }, function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", "tpi/skutch.jpg");
                }   // <-- remove this one
                });
            });
```

Note also that a nicer way to initialise your array is as follows:

```
var sb = ['tpi/speech1.png',
          'tpi/speech2.png',
          'tpi/speech3.png',
          'tpi/speech4.png',
          'tpi/speech5.png'];
```

The way you did it *works* but why type out all the `sb[0] =` parts when you don't need to?

Comment: thanx ..I'll remember that for arrays